# How to change Lightswitch browser icon?

Tags: browser, icons, visual-studio-lightswitch

I tried to change the application icon but it only works with the desktop version , when i convert to web the icon didn't display correctly , only blank page icon displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the Lightswitch team has apparently not thought of this... at least since Visual Studio 2012.

It is a manual process, so *each time you publish* you will have to put this in the default.htm file located in the main directory

```
<head>
...    
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico" />
...
</head>
```

Where favicon.ico is the URL of somewhere on the server/computer.

This line is to be placed **within** the head tags.

Answer (score 0):

It can't be done through Visual Studio. It is a manual process. For the highest compatibility, you need to create an image that is 16 x 16 pixels in a `.ico` format and name it `favicon.ico`. You will then need to place it in the root directory of your website which should be located at `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyWebApp`.

For more information on favicons, see the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon).